# Adding a domain alias in ISPConfig

Tags: dns, domain, redirection

ISPConfig 3 has the option to add Alias Domains in the menu under the Sites tab.

The challenge is I do not understand 2 of the fields that I have to supply:

Redirect Type (what is this?) Options:
 - No redirect
 - No flag
 - last
 - break
 - redirect
 - permanent
 - proxy
What does each of these options mean, and what are the implications of choosing it?

SEO Redirect:
 - No redirect
 - domain.tld => www.domain.tld
 - www.domain.tld => domain.tld
 - *.domain.tld => domain.tld
 - *.domain.tld => www.domain.tld
 - * => domain.tld
 - * => www.domain.tld
I understand this SOMEWHAT better, except for the last 2 options. But please can someone explain the real-life implications of these?

Let's consider this scenario:
I want to set alias.com to be alias of original.com
alias.com, original.com, other.com and another.com all point to the same IP.
original.com, other.com and another.com are 3 different websites.

I have Googled for a couple of hours, but so far haven't been able to find any good documentation/explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISPConfig3 presents webserver-specific flags (redirect types):

**Apache**

- R: Use of the [R] flag causes a HTTP redirect to be issued to the browser. If a fully-qualified URL is specified (that is, including `http://servername/)` then a redirect will be issued to that location. Otherwise, the current servername will be used to generate the URL sent with the redirect.
- L: The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. In most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed.
- R,L: You will almost always want to use [R] in conjunction with [L] (that is, use [R,L]) because on its own, the [R] flag prepends http://thishost[:thisport] to the URI, but then passes this on to the next rule in the ruleset, which can often result in 'Invalid URI in request' warnings.

**nginx**

- last: Completes processing of rewrite directives, after which searches for corresponding URI and location. Huh? In the scenario described in the question this means location is rewritten and passed on to original.com
- break: Completes processing of rewrite directives and breaks location lookup cycle by not doing any location lookup and internal jump at all. Huh? In the above scenario this means that location belongs to alias.com
- redirect: Returns temporary redirect with code 302; it is used if the substituting line begins with http://.
- permanent: Returns permanent redirect with code 301.

That leaves us with 3 options

- no redirect - this will be destined for original.com root instead of a subdirectory of the same
- no flag - if no flag is set then default server setting is used
- proxy - not strictly a redirect. I understand that this is a 305 - The requested resource is only available through a proxy, whose address is provided in the response.

Answer (score 0):

Web hoster name server. Delegates a DNS zone to use the given authoritative name servers. 
Web hosting usually makes these records yourself. But there are other options.

```
domain.tld. NS ns1.<dns1>
domain.tld. NS ns2.<dns2>
```

The main entry. It will refer to all the aliases and write back.

```
domain.tld. A <IP>
```

Wildcard aliases. Think of it as a shortcut combination and permutation. Or alias and substitution.

```
*.domain.tld. CNAME domain.tld.
```

Required entry for postal entries to the letters do not end up in the spam list.

```
mail.domain.tld. A  <IP>
```

domain.tld => www.domain.tld: 
This is not a redirect alias. It is very common, as the user enters the site as `domain.tld` and `www.domain.tld`. The number of aliases can be as large as patience))). That is, very much.

For simplicity, assume that it is a shortcut.

`www.domain.tld.` - "shortcut"; `domain.tld` - "document";

```
www.domain.tld. CNAME domain.tld.
```

Mail account with priority mail address.

```
domain.tld. MX 10 mail.domain.tld.
```

if need PTR

```
<IP>/<mask> PTR domain.tld.
```

`*.domain.tld => www.domain.tld` - not need, `www.domain.tld` and `domain.tld` one site or not CNAME.

`* => domain.tld` , `* => www.domain.tld` - error

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I'm not quite sure I understand. There are multiple domains and multiple sites on this IP. The "alias" domain already points to the IP. The question now is how do I set it up in ISPConfig so that it is alias of the correct site. Additionally, what do the options Redirect type and SEO redirect mean?

Comment: @OC2PS I'm not SEO. But I know of only one combination of SEO and redirect. Note in the HTTP header tag on the movement of the page if it took place. You can see it here http://www.seomoz.org/learn-seo/redirection .Everything else is setting records for DNS or specify the subject matter in another way.

Comment: Not being SEO is fine. Just help me understand what each of the REDIRECT TYPES mean.

Comment: @OC2PS Those that link to, or those that are described in your question?

Comment: Per my question.

Comment: @OC2PS Then just see a pattern that I brought. I'll try to comment on it in detail, in those parts which are especially needed.

Comment: Seems somehow I'm not getting through. What do the following Redirect Type options mean: - No redirect - No flag - last - break - redirect - permanent - proxy