# ISPConfig Redirect types changed

Tags: redirection, isp

I just installed a new version of ISPConfig on my server.

I used to have the redirect type `R` but in the new version there are no letters, just full names like `redirect` or `proxy`.

Can anybody tell me if the new `redirect` is the same as my old `R`?

Thanks!

BTW: A matching list for the old parameters and the new ones would be great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution. The change of the types seem to be related to the change of the underlying machine:

[Here is a good post explaining the issue](https://superuser.com/a/593553/138877).